# Get ArrayList Index according to HashMap Key Value

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I Have a ArrayList as `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList_LatLong = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` in which I put HashMap into that ArrayList. The HashMap key-value pair suppose as follows

```
map.put(key1,value1);  
map.put(key2,value2);  
map.put(key3,value3);  
map.put(key4,value4);  
map.put(key5,value5);
```

Now I want ArrayList Index according to Value1, that means I have Value1 and I want the respective ArrayList Index so that I can get Other Values also from the respective HashMap.

Comment: Explain with example..

Answer (score 4):

try this--->

```
public static int getIndexOFValue(String value, List<Map<String, String>> listMap) {

    int i = 0;
    for (Map<String, String> map : listMap) {
        if (map.containsValue(value)) {
            return i;
        } 
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to defined it this way :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> arrayList_LatLong = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

When you want to get the index in the list you just gotta do :

```
Integer newIndex = arrayList_LatLong.get(someIndex).get("aKey");
HashMap<String, Integer> indexes = arrayList_LatLong.get(newIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

Here i am searching for the value "android". you can change it according to your code

```
String value = "android";

int getIndex(){
  int i = -1;
  for (Map<String, String> map : arrayList_LatLong) {
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
      if (map.get(key).equals(value)) {

          i = arrayList_LatLong.indexOf(map);

      }
   } 
}

return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public static int getIndexOFkey(String key, ArrayList> listMap) {

```
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<listMap.size(); i++)
    {
        if(listMap.get(i).get("id").equalsIgnoreCase(key))
        {
         return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: How about indenting the first line and commenting a bit the code?